# Reading A Datafile, Calculate the Sum with Data given

Tags: c

I was able to print out the sum of each salespeople, but the math is a bit off by one product for each person. Can someone just point out this obvious mistake for me? 
Visit https://www.dropbox.com/s/itxiuabj25r8j45/Albatross.txt for the "Albatross.txt" file.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){

    FILE*fp;
    fp=fopen("Albatross.txt", "r");
    if (fp==NULL){
        printf ("Error: can't open file.\n");}
    else{
        printf ("File opened successfully.\n");}

    int person,
        product,
        price,
        total,
        sum;

    printf("File Contents: \n");
    int i,j=1;
    //int A[person][product][price];
    for (i = 0; i<20; i++)
    {
         int A[person][product][price];
         fscanf(fp, "%d" "%d" "%d", &person, &product, &price);
         printf ("%d %d %d\n", person, product, price);

    }
    for (i=1; i<5; i++){
         total = total + price;

         printf( "Salesperson %d : \t%d\n", i,total);
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are not doing the sum of actual sales of each sales person isn't? Try changing the values to random values. `total = total + price;` depends on the last entry of salesman 4.

Comment: You actually managed to compile this?? The line A[person][product][price] is just wrong. You might want to read this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm    I suspect that you intended to add 5 products to each salesperson and therefore your line: for(i=1;i<5;i++) should be: for(i=0;i<5;i++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_OF_REC 20
#define NUM_OF_PSN 5 //+1 , 0 is dummy

typedef struct rec {
    int person;
    int product;
    int price;
} Record;

int main(){
    FILE*fp;
    fp=fopen("Albatross.txt", "r");
    if (fp==NULL){
        printf ("Error: can't open file.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else{
        printf ("File opened successfully.\n");
    }

    Record A[NUM_OF_REC];
    int total[NUM_OF_PSN] = {0};

    printf("File Contents: \n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_REC; i++){
        fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &A[i].person, &A[i].product, &A[i].price);
        printf ("%d %d %d\n", A[i].person, A[i].product, A[i].price);
        total[A[i].person] += A[i].price;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    for (i=1; i< NUM_OF_PSN; i++){
        printf("Salesperson %d : \t%d\n", i, total[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful! Especially the proper way of using the arrays! I was kinda in doubt with that too.